# TSC: what does --target ES3 compatibility flag do?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compatibility, tsc, ecmascript-3

I installed typescript npm package:

```
npm install typescript
```

and ran

```
node_modules\.bin\tsc doodle.ts -t ES3
```

Where `doodle.ts` has:

```
var test = document.querySelector('.test');
```

It echoed back the same in output `doodle.js`.

How to configure it so in the output, I get:

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName('.test')[0];
```

Shouldn't `-t ES3` flag take care of such compatibility aspects?

Comment: JavaScript and the DOM API are separate things, so no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flags like `-es5`, `es3`, etc do indeed take care of supporting transpiling of advanced TS/ES6 features into their equivalent (when possible) in previous versions of JavaScript (for example, with [for..off](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#forof-support)).

However, `document.querySelector` is not part of the ECMAScript standard. It's part of the DOM API, and ignored by TypeScript. The transpiler is not trying to provide browser compatibility, but rather, *language* compatibility. You might find shims that say they're for specific ECMAScript versions that roll API shims into it, but that's a misunderstanding as they're not exactly the same thing.

With TypeScript, you still need to use shims for missing DOM features that are browser-specific.

Comment: It should be stated that ES5 is also not supported in transpiling. So `Array.prototype.reduce` or object getters / setters are not supported when using the ES3 option.